# Nuxtjs2 iPhone keyboard is not shown on PWA

Tags: ios, vue.js, nuxt.js, progressive-web-apps, nuxtjs2

I have run into a problems with iPhone default keyboard while using NuxtJS.

It happened when I installed 2 PWA apps to homescreen.
The keyboard was missing (refer my screenshot for example).

Steps to reproduce problems

1. Installing 2 PWA apps (save them to Home Screen)
2. Open the 1st app, focus on input fields (my website)
   => keyboard was showing properly
3. Click to Home button, back to Home Screen
4. Open the 2nd app, focus on input fields (in this case I used Pinterest)
   => keyboard was missing on this step

It works on Android perfectly...

[Sample screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Du2gT.png)

Source code for this problems, FYI

```
<ValidationProvider :name="$t('authenticate.form_data._email')" vid="email" rules="required|email" v-slot="{ errors }">
    <div class="email-input mb-4">
        <label for="email" class="block text-gray-400 text-sm mb-1">
            {{ $t('authenticate.form_data._email') }}</label>
        <input id="email"
            class="shadow appearance-none borderrounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 mb-3 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"
            type="text"
            :placeholder="$t('authenticate.form_data._email_pl')"
            aria-describedby="emailHelp"
            v-model="formData.email"
            autofocus
            @blur="hiddenKeyboard"
            ref="inputFocus">

        <span class="text-xs text-red-700" id="emailHelp">{{
            errors[0]
          }}</span>
    </div>
</ValidationProvider>
```